# Bulk action using PHP for mysql entries

Tags: php, mysql, bulk

We are showing results in a table from a MySQL database with checkboxes inside it. How can we delete many rows simultaneously if the user ticks 5 rows and clicks the delete button?

Comment: Accept your recent questions.

Comment: So we should whip up an entire form handling system for you, without knowing anything about how your database is structured, the form is designed, etc..? "We want the code" isn't going to win you any friends here.

Comment: Are you trying to ask how you can display rows from a database, with a checkbox to mark that row for deletion, so that when the page is posted, it will delete all the checked rows?

Comment: And show your efforts so far before ordering code to be done for you

Comment: How about this? http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/8.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form method="post">

    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="123" /> Element 1 <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="5434" /> Element 2 <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="24" /> Element 3 <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="76" /> Element 4 <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="delete" />

</form>
```

PHP:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {

  $ids = array_walk($_POST['id'], 'intval');
  mysql_query('DELETE FROM table WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $ids) . ')');

}
```

P.S. I want points !

Comment: Shouldn't `$_POST['id']` come before `'intval'` in the `array_walk()` function?...just saying. I tried implementing your answer the way it is and I got a fatal error....I reversed the position of the arguements and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the PHP code, but building an SQL query like this will solve your problem:

```
DELETE FROM foo WHERE id IN ( … );
```

See the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/expressions.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

With PDOStatement like this

```
$statement = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?";
$conn = new PDO($dns,$user,$pass);
$conn->beginTransaction();
$query = $conn->prepare($statement);
foreach($params as $p){ //$params are your checked id's
    $query->bindParam(1,$p);
    if($query->execute()){
        echo "ok";
    }else{
        $conn->rollBack();
        exit("Error");
    }
}
$conn->commit();
```